# Testing a React App in with Microsoft Edge Canary

Tags: reactjs, command-line-interface, microsoft-edge

I want to run `npm start` on my React app and have the browser opened be Microsoft Edge Canary.  I am working a on a Mac.  I am able to test other browsers by running

```
BROWSER= firefox npm start
```

or

```
BROWSER= safari npm start
```

However I haven't been able to find any command that will run the app in Edge Canary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this documentation](https://github.com/sindresorhus/open#app), you could also pass in the browser app's full path to make react app open in certain browser.

In my side, I use a `.env` file to set environment variables. In `.env`, I add the `BROWSER` key with value of the location of Edge Canary in my computer like this:

```
BROWSER = C:\Users\yuzhou\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge SxS\Application\msedge.exe
```

Then I run `npm start`, the react app will [open in Edge Canary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn68O.gif). So I think it should be the same in your situation. You could try to use the full path of Edge Canary in your computer to make it open in Edge Canary.